# If every quotient group of a group G by non-trivial normal subgroups is abelian, G is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

> If every quotient group of a group G by non-trivial normal subgroups is abelian, G is abelian.

I'm asked about the veracity of this statement. I thought about the group $\mathrm{D_3}$ and the only normal subgroup that I came across was $\mathrm{\{\mathbb{id},\rho,\rho^2}\}$, that has index 2, so it's normal, but I'm not sure about how I can efficiently show that its quotient is abelian.

Comment: The quotient of $D_3$ by a subgroup of order $3$ has order $2$ by Lagrange's theorem. How many groups of order 2 do you know?

Comment: There is only one up to isomorphism, it's abelian, so the quotient group'd be an abelian group too

Comment: @J P: exactly!  To have a complete solution though, you need to prove that $C=\{\mathrm{id},\rho,\rho^2\}$ is the only normal subgroup of $D_3$ (in your OP you just say you noticed that $C$ was normal).  There are lots of ways of doing this (D_3 is small enough it is not too hard to list *all* of its subgroups even) but it is worth working out a proof for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a non-abelian simple group. Does this satisfy the condition?

Comment: For n $\geq$ 5, $\mathrm{A_n}$ is simple and non-abelian, so it'd satisfy the condition, isn't it?

Comment: @JP I was answering as to how to tell whether or not the quoted statement is true. I agree those are nonabelian examples that satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** What is the order of the quotient group $G/H$ if $G = D_3$, $H=\mathrm{\{\mathbb{id},\rho,\rho^2}\}$? What does this tell about it?